# Trying to allow MAC address whitelist to take effect without needing to reboot Pi

Tags: networking, access-point, troubleshooting, newbie

I am using a Raspberry Pi 3B with PiOS and I followed these tutorials for setting up a raspberry pi as a WAP and enabling MAC address filtering...  https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-3-as-an-access-point/all    and   https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=200798

I currently have gotten the MAC address filter to work, so that when my whitelist.txt file is empty, nothing can connect to the access point. When I update the whitelist.txt with the MAC addresses I want to be allowed, those devices can connect. I have one question however, after adding the MAC addresses, it won't allow me to connect my devices until I reboot the Pi. It's not a huge deal (usually takes a minute or so), but I want to know if there's any way to not have to reboot the Pi to allow my devices to connect once their MAC addresses have been added and saved. I am relatively new to Linux so I know that there is most likely an easy answer that I just have no clue about.

Comment: did you read the webpage at the second link that you posted?

Comment: Yes, but because I used the first link to create the access point which is slightly different than how that user created it, the reload command for that directory does not work for me.

Comment: there must still be a daemon of some kind that can be restsrted

Comment: I'm sure there is, but considering I don't even know what a daemon is, I don't think I will be able to find it on my own haha.